# Unable to submit changes from local master to perforce depo using git-p4

Tags: git, github, perforce, git-p4

I am Git user and having hard time with Perfoce submit so using git-p4 on Windows platform. 
I was able to clone and sync a depot on my local machine however unable to submit my changes on Perforce depot back using git-p4 submit.

Since git-p4 command did not work. i downloaded from [git-p4.py](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-p4.py)! .  Then executed following commands :

`C:\fold\fold2> python2.7 C:\here\git.p4.py clone //depot/main/Tool/repo2/@all`

Success with `fast-import failed.`

`C:\fold\fold2> python2.7 C:\here\git.p4.py sync` 
successful

Then did some change in C:\fold\fold2...\repo2\utils.py

`C:\fold\fold2> git add .`

`C:\fold\fold2> git commit -m "git p4 submit change".`

`C:\fold\fold2> python2.7 C:\here\git.p4.py submit`

Actions after submit command :

```
Synchronozing p4 checkout ...

... -files up to date 
('Applying', 'bda666969 myuser:git p4 submit change')

//depot/main/Tool/repo2/utils.py#6 - opened for edit 
Submission cancelled, undoing p4 changes.

//depot/main/Tool/repo2/utils.py#6 - was edit, reverted 

traceback File : "C:\here\git.p4.py line 4172" in module 
.....
WindowsError [Error 2] The system can nit find the file specified
```

Here i am not sure for which file git-p4 is erroring out as i have a utils.py in local repo and committed same utils.py to local master successfully.

Am i missing something in commit or submit process ?

Comment: Is it possible someone else edited the file in Perforce? You might need to do a git-p4 rebase first to ensure your changes are clean commits on the remote base.

Comment: Possibly more of the traceback might indicate more of the error - it's possible that git-p4 doesn't work properly on Windows.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder I've sync'ed that file again with P4 depot but error remains same. Can you please recommend anything which helps to commit code to P4 depot using git. I just want to check diff b/t my local master changes and depot master and git is very useful in that, specailly in code review process.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible sources of error.

First, a sync is not enough, you must do a rebase. `git p4 sync` only imports the new changes from the Perforce server into your git repository. After that happened, and if there were in fact new CLs on the server, you can see that the `p4/master` branch points to a different commit than before. Example: You cloned at commit A, and now you have two local commits B and C. So p4/master points at A, master at C.

```
A-----B-----C
^           ^- master
+- p4/master
```

Now after sync, two commits D and E were imported, so p4/master points at E.

```
A-----B-----C
 \          ^- master
  \
   \--D-----E
            ^- p4/master
```

Before you can `git p4 submit` your local changes, you must make sure that all your local changes come after the commit that `p4/master` points to. And that is what the `git p4 rebase` is for. It takes all your local changes and plays them back onto `p4/master`:

```
A-----B-----C
 \          
  \
   \--D-----E-----B'----C'
            ^           ^- master
            - p4/master
```

If there are no other commits that depend on C (e. g. a stash), git will clean up and you'll end up with:

```
A-----D-----E-----B'----C'
            ^           ^- master
            - p4/master
```

After the sync, but before the rebase, `master` and `p4/master` might have a common ancestor. After the rebase, `p4/master` will be an ancestor of `master`.

Another possible source of error I can think of is that you touched the Perforce workspace that `git p4` is using in any way. Make sure to have a Perforce workspace reserved for `git p4`, and don't ever make any manual changes to it.

---

Even though `git p4` is not officially supported on Windows, I've been using it for several months now, and I found it to work flawlessly so far. And it's far better than having to use Perforce supplied tooling for daily work.

(Edited to correct typo)